# Variance component analysis with lme4

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am beginner with lme4 and I am seeking some advice on how to carry a variance component analysis.

The data come from a real-world scenario, not from a designed experiment, resulting in a complex nesting structure:

- *"Students"* are examined on 4 different practical *"Topics"*.
- For each topic the performance (*"Scores"*) of the students is rated by a different *"Rater"*.
- Also, since the cohort of students is very large, this examination process is further divided multiple times: two *"Circuits"* (first and second) are running in parallel twice a day (*"Session 1"* and *"Session 2"*). Finally the exams goes on for several *"Days"* ("1" , ... , "D").

To sum up, here are the factors with their levels:

- Days        : {1, ..., D}
- Sessions    : {1, 2}
- Circuit     : {First, Second}
- Topics      : {1, 2, 3, 4}
- Raters      : {1, ... , R}
- Students    : {1, ... , S}

Therefore, the data set (just for Day == 1) I am working on has the following structure:

```
Day    Session  Circuit      Topics      Raters      Students    Scores
1          1  First              1            1           1      0.78
1          1  First              1            1           2      0.72
1          1  First              1            1           3      0.60
1          1  First              2            2           1      0.91
1          1  First              2            2           2      0.74
1          1  First              2            2           3      0.16
1          1  First              3            3           1      0.95
1          1  First              3            3           2      0.89
1          1  First              3            3           3      0.85
1          1  First              4            4           1      0.51
1          1  First              4            4           2      0.96
1          1  First              4            4           3      0.40
1          1  Second             1            5           6      0.06
1          1  Second             1            5           7      0.98
1          1  Second             1            5           8      0.65
1          1  Second             2            6           6      0.51
1          1  Second             2            6           7      0.06
1          1  Second             2            6           8      0.14
1          1  Second             3            7           6      0.85
1          1  Second             3            7           7      0.66
1          1  Second             3            7           8      0.17
1          1  Second             4            8           6      0.58
1          1  Second             4            8           7      0.17
1          1  Second             4            8           8      0.63
1          2  First              1            9           9      0.41
1          2  First              1            9           10     0.59
1          2  First              1            9           11     0.33
1          2  First              2           10           9      0.39
1          2  First              2           10           10     0.33
1          2  First              2           10           11     0.87
1          2  First              3           11           9      0.50
1          2  First              3           11           10     0.09
1          2  First              3           11           11     0.97
1          2  First              4           12           9      0.74
1          2  First              4           12           10     0.59
1          2  First              4           12           11     0.47
1          2  Second             1           13           14     0.42
1          2  Second             1           13           15     0.77
1          2  Second             1           13           16     0.05
1          2  Second             2           14           14     0.48
1          2  Second             2           14           15     0.88
1          2  Second             2           14           16     0.53
1          2  Second             3           15           14     0.95
1          2  Second             3           15           15     0.85
1          2  Second             3           15           16     0.89
1          2  Second             4           16           14     0.41
1          2  Second             4           16           15     0.17
1          2  Second             4           16           16     0.53
```

What I would like to estimate is how much of the variation in the "Scores" can be associated with a given factor ("Day", "Session", "Raters", etc...).

For this purpose I was trying to apply a linear-mixed effects model. What I find confusing is the nesting structure of my variables.

Using the coding from the library lme4 I would be inclined to write:

```
lmer( Scores ~ 1 +  ( 1 | Days ) +
                    ( 1 | Sessions ) +
                    ( 1 | Circuit ) +
                    ( 1 | Topics ) +
                    ( 1 | Raters ) +
                    ( 1 | Students ) +               
                    ( 1 | Students : Topics ) + # Students are nested into Topics, Circuit, Sessions and Days  
                    ( 1 | Students : Circuit ) +
                    ( 1 | Students : Sessions ) +
                    ( 1 | Students : Days ) +
                    ( 1 | Topics : Circuit ) + # Topics are nested into Circuit, Sessions and Days 
                    ( 1 | Topics : Sessions ) +
                    ( 1 | Topics : Days ) +
                    ( 1 | Circuit : Sessions ) + # Circuit are nested into Sessions and Days
                    ( 1 | Circuit : Days ) +
                    ( 1 | Sessions : Days ) + # Sessions are nested into Days
                    ( 1 | Topics : Circuit : Sessions : Days ) +
                    ( 1 | Topics : Circuit : Sessions ) )
```

Is this the proper way to extract the variances components associated with each factor?